# Where is documentation of -H:... options of GraalVM native-image?

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Substrate VM documentation on GitHub (e.g. [CONFIGURE.md](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/CONFIGURE.md) mentions multiple `-H:...` options like `-H:ReflectionConfigurationResources` or `-H:ConfigurationFileDirectories`. Where can reference documentation of these options be found? [GraalVM Reference > Native Image](https://docs.oracle.com/en/graalvm/enterprise/19/guide/reference/native-image.html) gives just a basic overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output of `native-image --help` suggests to call `native-image --help-extra` which suggests to call

```
native-image --expert-options-all
```

which prints documented list of options: https://gist.github.com/happylynx/ce642816411ee5c98f04fedd80f4c417.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are different levels for the command `help`:

- `native-image --help` prints default help message with regular options used for generating native image
- `native-image --help-extra` prints help on non-standard options, it shows clearly the usage of the next two options
- `native-image --expert-options` prints help for more advanced options to use by experts
- `native-image --expert-options-all` prints all image building options available, it is clear in the output message that this last command should be used at your own risk

Therefore, you can append a grep expression to one of the four commands above and retrieve the help about a specific command. Here is an example:

```
native-image --expert-options | grep -A 1 ReflectionConfigurationResources
```

> I am using `grep` with `-A 1` to show one more line in case the first one is truncated

The previous command show the output bellow:

```
-H:ReflectionConfigurationResources=... Resources describing program elements to be made available for reflection (see ReflectionConfigurationFiles). Default: None
```

Comment: @czerny, can you please check one of the given answers so it will be well noticeable for future post viewers.